# Communicating with USB Dongle, No USB endpoints found error

Tags: java, usb

I am following [this](http://libusbjava.sourceforge.net/wp/res/demos/ReadWrite.java.html) tutorial from the [libusbjava](http://libusbjava.sourceforge.net/wp/) library. However, when I try to run it, it throws the following error.

```
ch.ntb.usb.USBException: No USB endpoints found. Check the device configuration
```

Here is the relevant part from the program

```
public static void testDevice(){



    //Vendor ID, Product ID
    Device dev = USB.getDevice((short) 0x0bda, (short) 0x2838); 


    try{
        //Data to write to device
        byte[] data = new byte[]{0,1,2,3}; 
        //Data to read from device
        byte[] readData = new byte[data.length];


        dev.open(1, 0, -1);

        dev.writeInterrupt(0x81, data, data.length, 2000, false);

        dev.readBulk(0x81, readData, readData.length, 2000, false);

        logData(readData); 

        dev.close(); 


    }
    catch(USBException e){
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

Here is the information from the device from USB View

```
Device Descriptor:
bcdUSB:             0x0200
bDeviceClass:         0x00
bDeviceSubClass:      0x00
bDeviceProtocol:      0x00
bMaxPacketSize0:      0x40 (64)
idVendor:           0x0BDA
idProduct:          0x2838
bcdDevice:          0x0100
iManufacturer:        0x01
iProduct:             0x02
iSerialNumber:        0x03
bNumConfigurations:   0x01

ConnectionStatus: DeviceConnected
Current Config Value: 0x01
Device Bus Speed:     Full
Device Address:       0x02
Open Pipes:              1

Endpoint Descriptor:
bEndpointAddress:     0x81
Transfer Type:        Bulk
wMaxPacketSize:     0x0200 (512)
bInterval:            0x00
```

Comment: What about the interface descriptor?

Comment: I don't know where to get that information. Can I access it via USB View?

Answer (score 1):

Your Device has one `bulk IN` type endpoint - which can only send data to the Host in bulk mode.
But you try to write to it:

`dev.writeInterrupt(0x81, data, data.length, 2000, false);`

This cannot work, you would need an `interrupt OUT` type endpoint for that. It would also have a different endpoint address.

Comment: There seems to be a writebulk method, but the part that is throwing the error is dev.open(1, 0, -1)

Comment: Oddly enough, I just ran it again and the No USB endpoints found error is gone. However, it is now saying that the endpoint 0x81 is invalid. I do not know why it started to work.